# Multiple Controllers in .net core

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

How do you route with multiple controllers? I am confused... I have it working for logins but when I try to do with another task it cant find the page, though the URL is correct.. I had this folder under the main views but moved it to an area to see if that was my issue. I generated the CompanyInformationsController from scaffolding, and it works if I just make it a standard link off the same home controller, but as soon as I try to do CRUD operations and it creates the controller and folders I cant get it to route...

[image]

Controller

```
public class CompanyInformationsController : Controller
{
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;

    public CompanyInformationsController(ApplicationDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    // GET: CompanyInformations
    

    public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
    {
        return View(await _context.CompanyInformations.ToListAsync());
    }
```

CSHTML

```
<li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index">
                        <i class="ni ni-tv-2 text-primary"></i> Dashboard
                    </a>
                </li>

                                    <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" asp-area="Onboarding" asp-controller="CompanyInformations" asp-action="Index">
                        <i class="ni ni-tv-2 text-primary"></i> Clients
                    </a>
                </li>
```

Program

```
    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
//    endpoints.MapAreaControllerRoute(
//    name: "Onboarding",
//    areaName: "Onboarding",
//    pattern: "Onboarding/{controller=Onboarding}/{action=Index}"
//);

    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
        name: "areaRoute",
        pattern: "{area:exists}/{controller}/{action}"
    );

    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
        name: "default",
        pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}"
    );

});
```

Answer (score 1):

By default, your routing will be generated from your controller name excluding the '**Controller**' text from the controller name.

You can provide custom routing using Attribute routing on the Controller level. You can add any text on the routing. Like below:

```
[Route("CompanyInformations")]
public class CompanyInformationsController : Controller
{
}
```

Comment: Correct. I get that, however I am specifying the controller in the link to route. I even specify in the link, which is how I added my user and role links with their individual controllers.  `                            <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" asp-area="Onboarding" asp-controller="CompanyInformations" asp-action="Index">
                            <i class="ni ni-tv-2 text-primary"></i> Clients
                        </a>
                    </li>`

Answer (score 0):

I deleted and regenerated the scaffolding and its working..... Not sure why since I have done this already....

Comment: In your commented section， {controller=Onboarding} is should be  {controller=CompanyInformations}.

Comment: For example, when you break the point to look at the Post and Get methods of the edit action, since your previous routing template did not add an id, but scaffolding is mapped according to the id of the routing template, your id value is 0, but when When you add the id to the route, you can receive the incoming value.

Answer (score 0):

Below is my suggestion: Add `{id}` to your route

In Startup.cs:

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapAreaControllerRoute(
                     name: "Onboarding",
                     areaName: "Onboarding",
                     pattern: "Onboarding/{controller=CompanyInformations}/{action=Index}/{id?}"
               );
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                      name: "areaRoute",
                      pattern: "{area:exists}/{controller}/{action}/{id}"
   
               );
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });
```

In controller: Add  `[Area("Onboarding")]`

```
    [Area("Onboarding")]
    public class CompanyInformationsController : Controller
    {
        private readonly Mul1Context _context;

        public CompanyInformationsController(Mul1Context context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        // GET: CompanyInformations
        public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
        {
            return View(await _context.CompanyInformation.ToListAsync());
        }
}
```

result:

[image]